# Get "desired" string from RegExp

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a little ticketing-system in PHP.

In the configuration of my component you can specify a RegExp for your ticket-"marker". If you specify:

```
/\[Ticket-ID: (\S+)\]\s*(.*)/
```

all e-mails with `[Ticket-ID: 123456789] My Subject` are recognized as valid ticket-messages.

Well, but now I would like to generate valid ticket-ids for outgoing mails.

So I got an ticket-id like `12345` and the title `test`; now I would like to insert this ID into the user-configured RegExp, so that the outgoing has the subject:

`[Ticket-ID: 12345] test`

Example: User configures the following RegEx to detect emails that are attached to a ticket:

`/\[Ticket-ID: (\S+)\]\s*(.*)/` Now the support-staff wants to answer to this ticket:

```
<?php
$this->title = "[Ticket-ID: $this->id] $this->title";
?>
```

would be the static way to create the title.

If the user changes the RegEx, the staff would send with an incorrect title.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can start by trying something and showing us your effort?

Comment: Could you please precise what the problem is? BTW, if the problem is with the code, please post the code with what you have already tried. Just building a dynamic regex seems to be a trivial task.

Comment: Okay, I will specify my problem (and I do not have an idea to solve it, so there is no code so far).

If a user configures the component in the way that the string `[Ticket: 12345]` will be recognized as a `ticket` with id `12345` I also would like to use this "style" of subject-prefix on outgoing mails.

My idea was to get the configured RegEx and "insert" the data from the created ticket: If I create a new ticket with ID "3456" I would like to get the configured RegEx and create `[Ticket: 3456] My Subject` dynamically.

Comment: Please have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/NyLTBC), are you trying to achieve something like that?

Comment: Hi and thank you. Yes, something like that. The problem is: I only have the given RegEx (e.g. `/\[Ticket-ID: (\S+)\]\s*(.*)/`). I do not have any further information (and still have to insert my id and subject into the given RegEx).

Maybe this is not possible at all?

Comment: If understand you correctly you want to parse the regex to use it as a template for your mails. That's a **major** task if you're to allow full regex. (And how to "reverse" variable length repetitions). You could possibly limit what you allow and (in it's simplest form) simply replace a string like `(\S+)` with the ticket number. Or even make a pseudo language like `[Ticket-ID: $ID$]` and convert it to a regex for input and replacing the tokens for output.

Comment: Don't allow the user to define the regex, it will only get you headaches.

Comment: Hi ClasG, this "pseudo-language" was the way I chose now.

Thank you for your help :-)